# How to know BLE beacon is out of range with Android BLE api 21

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-5.0-lollipop, android-bluetooth, ibeacon-android

The new Android BLE api (starting from api 21) allows to get callback on beacon found easily with [onBatchScanResults](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanCallback.html#onBatchScanResults%28java.util.List%3Candroid.bluetooth.le.ScanResult%3E%29) but is it possible to get some kind of info when beacon is out of range?

I suppose that I can do i manually - remember list of last seen beacons

```
public void onBatchScanResults (List<ScanResult> results)
```

and with next batch compare it with the last seen - but in that case I'd need to wake up the device - lets say - every minute to check if sth has changed.

DISCLAIMER: I don't use ibeacon but some other BLE beacon but there's not tag like `beacon`

Comment: yeah that seems to be the only way to do it right now..remember list... otherwise would need to include a server with a mechanism from the beacon. Else, fundamentally it wouldn't be possible to detect if a beacon is not in range :) or maintain a list of your uuid- specific beacons and can check from the same

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a timer and maintain a list as you describe, as the APIs maintain no stateful knowkedge of disappearing devices.

---

A few tips:

1. Make your list be based on devices seen across multiple `onBatchScanResults` callbacks, because individual callbacks may not have as full list.
2. Use `AlarmManager` for your timer because it will wake up your app even if the CPU goes to sleep when the app is in the background.
3. Use a `Map` keyed by the the Mac address for your list of devices, and store a composite object that contains both a `BluetoothDevice` and a timestamp of when it was last detected.

Comment: Did you test power consumption for this approach?

Comment: See here:  http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/10/28/android-5.0-scanning.html  These tests were not using an AlarmManager, but are solely with the low latency Android 5.0 scanning with callbacks to `onBatchScanResults`

Comment: yeah, but it does not cover the case when you wake up the device at certaing moment to check if sth has changed; anyway - it seems that Android BLE api was not meant to detect out-of-range events, just in-range events; this is how they want to think about a beacon - sth that you can find, but not loose :)

Comment: To be clear, Android does not have any beacon APIs.  It only has lower level Bluetooth LE APIs.  That is the whole reason I wrote the Android Beacon Library.  http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/   It adds the exact functionality you describe, and for a variety of configurable beacon types.